# How do I stop kittens from nursing on my older cat who is not their mother?

Tags: cats, feeding, weaning

I got two kittens 6 weeks ago and they are currently about 4 months old. They nurse on my older cat everyday, several times a day. My older cat would stop them at first, but they are relentless so she eventually gave up and just sort of lets them do it now but I can tell she’s tired of it. I try to stop them too, by picking them up and moving them, but they just run right back.
Will they grow out of it or do I need to stop it? I have read about getting a bittering spray to help stop, but the reviews seem hit or miss and are mostly geared towards stopping pets from chewing/scratching furniture. Any tips would be very much appreciated!!